# How to wait for onBlur state update when submitting form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have a big form in a ScrollView with keyBoardShouldPersistTaps set to "handled", and are saving the the values entered into Global State when onBlur is called in a TextInput (the onChangeText is saved to local state within each component to be more performant).

The problem comes when my users are submitting the form, if they click on the submit button while still having a textinput in focus (with values in it) the submit call is run without the values from the textinput that was in focus when the submit button was pressed.

All other values in all other textinputs are submitted correctly, as the state has had time to update correctly.

How can I make sure that the onBlur and useState (which is async I know) is updated before the submit function is called?

Simplified code to explain my challenge ([expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@svarto/onblur-not-updating-state-in-time-for-submit)):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Button, Alert, TextInput, Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
      const [globalValue, setGlobalValue] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');
    const [localValue, setLocalValue] = React.useState(globalValue);

  return (
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"handled"} style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => setLocalValue(text)}
      value={localValue}
      onBlur={() => setGlobalValue(localValue)}
    />
            <Button
        title="Press me"
        onPress={() => {Keyboard.dismiss(); Alert.alert(globalValue);}}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Enter something into the textinput
2. Directly click the submit button
3. You will not see what you entered in the textinput because the submission fires before the state has updated from the onBlur

Steps to reproduce a working "submission":

1. Enter something into the textinput
2. click anywhere else to dismiss the keyboard
3. Click on the button and you will see what you entered into the textinput

Comment: you should do 'setText' in 'onChange' method. Is'nt it? Until you do that, 'text' property of state will not get updated which you tried to access 'onPress' of button.

Comment: This is a simplified example showing the problem, the reason I can't use onChangeText is that it is not performant enough when tied to global state. It writes global state for each letter which creates stuttering on Android which makes it unusable. So want to write to global state only once the entry is done (i.e. once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OLD CODE:** Can't you do as below or you have to use another state variable called 'text'?

```
export default function App() {
  const placeHolder = "Useless Placeholder";
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState(placeHolder);

  return (
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"handled"} style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value}
      onBlur={() => {
        onChangeText(value || placeHolder);
      }}
    />
    <Button
        title="Press me"
        onPress={() => {Keyboard.dismiss(); Alert.alert(value);}}
    />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

**Updated code:** This is the only way I can see as of now

```
export default function App() {
  const placeHolder = 'Useless Placeholder';
  const [globalValue, setGlobalValue] = React.useState(placeHolder); 
  const [localValue, setLocalValue] = React.useState(globalValue);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    if(placeHolder !== globalValue) {
      Alert.alert(globalValue);
    }      
  }, [globalValue]);

  return (
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"handled"} style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={text => setLocalValue(text)}
        value={localValue}
      />
      <Button
        title="Press me"
        onPress={() => {setGlobalValue(localValue)}}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Paveloosha, thank you for the reply! I updated my code example to try and explain what I am trying to do, I have a global state and local state, I need to submit the global value when user submits the form so I can't use only local state. The global state can't be used onChangeText as it becomes too costly performance wise, with stuttering and lagging happening on text entry. So I am trying to make the controlled TextInput use the local state until use is done, i.e. onBlur, and then pass it to global state.

Comment: @Svarto, I got your point but no way 'onBlur' is going to work. Only way is to use callBack function for setting state, which is 'useEffect' incase of functional component. Updated my code, please check if it is fine for you. Ref: https://upmostly.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-setstate-callback-in-react#:~:text=setState%20Callback%20in%20a%20Functional%20Component&text=However%2C%20the%20useState%20Hook%20does,is%20an%20array%20of%20dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `React.useCallback(()=>{},[])`

Here is the example code:

````js
export default function App() {
    const [globalValue, setGlobalValue] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');
    const [localValue, setLocalValue] = React.useState(globalValue);

    //React.useCallback make sure that localValue has been updated before setGlobalValue while using onBlur
    const handleOnBlue = React.useCallback(()=>{
        setGlobalValue(localValue);
    },[localValue])

  return (
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"handled"} style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => setLocalValue(text)}
      value={localValue}
      onBlur={handleOnBlue}
    />
            <Button
        title="Press me"
        onPress={() => {Keyboard.dismiss(); Alert.alert(globalValue);}}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).